# Java BufferedWriter.write

Tags: java, pipe, stdin, bufferedwriter

I want to set some input string to stdin so another process can read stdin as input. I used Java `BufferedWriter`. But how do I handle the case when the input the string is bigger than the pipe size or the other process doesn't read? Is there a API to check if the pipe is available for write?

```
BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p1.getOutputStream()));

stdin.write(inputToP2);

stdin.flush();
```

Comment: Why, do you get an error?

Comment: The process should be actively reading from the stdin, which will clear space in the buffer. As Maarten says, are you actually running into an issue here?

Comment: no, but just to be proactive since I got a code review feedback saying the write will be blocked if no one is reading from it

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I handle the case when the input the string is bigger than the pipe size

You don't have to. It will block until space is available.

> or the other process doesn't read?

Again, you will block until space is available. If the other process doesn't read, that's a bug in the other process.

> Is there a API to check if the pipe is available for write?

No. This is Java blocking I/O. It blocks. Java doesn't provide any other way to write to a process's input, or to see whether a blocking write will block.

> I got a code review feedback saying the write will be blocked if no one is reading from it

And that is correct, but what do they expect you to do about it? It's blocking I/O, that's how it works. Ask them what they expect you to do about it.

NB `stdin` is the name of an input, not an output. Don't use the name of an input for an output stream. It's input to the other process but it is output to yours. I wouldn't call it `stdout` either, it isn't your `stdout`. I would just call it `out` actually, or `processOut` if more specificity is required.